# Proof of trace of matrix

Tags: matrices

I made a proof that trace(AB)=trace(BA). I cannot find any mistake. If there is one or more please let me know in comments.
Thank you!
[image: Trace of matrix]

Comment: Is this a joke? The dimensions of $A,B$ are not convenient. $AB$ is not a square matrix, and $BA$ is not defined at all. Moreover, you multiplication is really particular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it should be pointed out that the dimensions do not allow for the operations you suggested, namely you cannot form $D$ in this manner. But that is probably just a notation and you are interested in cases where this is not an issue.

The mistake is in the third line, imho - it simply does not hold. The issue is that $A$ is defined row-wise and $B$ column-wise. Hence the multiplication of matrices allows for an easy notation in case of $C:=A*B$ *but not in case* of $D:=B*A$ (of course unless these matrices are symmetrical).